# Drawing oval using drawOval() method

Tags: java, swing, graphics

At first I wrote this class DrawOval.java as follows :-

```
public class DrawOval extends JPanel{
    private int diameter = 10;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.fillOval(10,10,diameter,diameter);
    }
    public void setDiameter(int newD){
        diameter = (newD>=0 ? newD : 10);
        repaint();
    }
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return new Dimension(200,200);
    }
    public Dimension getMinimumSize(){
        return getPreferredSize();
    }
}
```

then I wrote this class TheWindow.java as follows :-

```
public class TheWindow extends JFrame{
    private DrawOval myPanel;
    public TheWindow(){
        super("The title");
        myPanel = new DrawOval();
        myPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        add(myPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

At last I wrote the main class as follows:-

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        TheWindow w = new TheWindow();
        w.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        w.setSize(300,300);
        w.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

and the output is only a frame with a green background without any oval ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never call `setDiameter(...)` and so the field holds a 0 value and no oval will be drawn.

One solution is to try to remember to call this method every time you create a DrawOval object, but why force yourself to remember this? Instead make diameter a parameter of the constructor and make sure that the class has no default constructor so that it the diameter field **must** be set to some value on object creation. Another option is to give the diameter field a default value, so that even if it is never set explicitly, it will always be set implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You should call setDiameter method in order the oval shape to be drawn. 
But i think you should  merge this method with the paintComponent. By this way you should not care about calling the method.

What i mean is:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g, int newD){

    super.paintComponent(g);

    diameter = (newD>=0 ? newD : 10);
    repaint();          

    g.fillOval(10,10,diameter,diameter);

}
```

Comment: Please clarify: merge what with paintComponent?

Comment: I mean that you should put the code of the setDiameter method in the paintComponent. You do not need a separate method for this task. By this way you it will not be required to call this method. I will edit my answer to see what i mean.

Comment: Better to give diameter a default value, and never, I repeat **never** call `repaint()` inside of a `paint(Graphics g)` or `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method. Ever. This risks potential recursion and or bad side effects. Just don't do this or recommend this.